# How to change function so that the difference between target and any element is minimum?

Tags: c++

how can I change these two (or either of them) functions to get the minimum dist where dist=pow(target-v[i],2). I want to get the index of the element in the vector with the smallest distance from target considering that the vector is ordered and I want to find the element efficiently using binary search.
Thanks a lot.

```
int getClosest(int val1, int val2,int target, int i, int j)
{
    if (pow(target - val1,2) >= pow(val2 - target,2))
        return j;
    else
        return i;
}


// Returns element closest to target
int findClosest(vector<int> arr, int n, int target)
{
    // Corner cases
    if (target <= arr[0])
        return 0;
    if (target >= arr[n - 1])
        return n - 1;

    // Doing binary search
    int i = 0, j = n, mid = 0;
    while (i < j) {
        mid = (i + j) / 2;

        if (arr[mid] == target)
            return mid;

        /* If target is less than array element,
            then search in left */
        if (target < arr[mid]) {

            // If target is greater than previous
            // to mid, return closest of two
            if (mid > 0 && target > arr[mid - 1])
                {
                  return getClosest(arr[mid - 1],arr[mid], target, mid-1,mid);
                }
            /* Repeat for left half */
            j = mid;
        }

        // If target is greater than mid
        else {
            if (mid < n - 1 && target < arr[mid + 1])
                return getClosest(arr[mid],  arr[mid + 1], target, mid,mid+1);
            // update i
            i = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    // Only single element left after search
    return mid;
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: You don't need the power function. Positive powers of numbers get the relation of modules of numbers.

Comment: Prefer to use `(x * x)` instead of the `pow(x,2)`.  The multiplication is often faster, works with integers, and takes up less code space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to use *binary search algorithm*, you must be sure about the **given array or the vector is sorted or not**. If the vector is sorted then only you can apply binary search to find the index of the closest distance.

Now considering the given vector is sorted, we can apply binary search.

Another thing that I see in your code, into the `getClosest(int v1, int v2, int target, int i, int j)` method that you are squaring both side to check with the positive integers. Rather you can consider **mod operator** or `abs` method in cpp to do so. `abs` will take less time rather than `pow`.

**Modified Code:**

```cpp
int getClosest(int val1, int val2,int target, int i, int j)
    {
        if (abs(target - val1) >= abs(val2 - target))
            return j;
        else
            return i;
    }


// Returns element closest to target
int findClosest(vector<int> arr, int n, int target)
{
    // Corner cases
    if (target <= arr[0])
        return 0;
    if (target >= arr[n - 1])
        return n - 1;

    // Doing binary search
    int i = 0, j = n, mid = 0;
    while (i < j) {
        mid = (i + j) / 2;

        if (arr[mid] == target)
            return mid;

        /* If target is less than array element,
            then search in left */
        if (target < arr[mid]) {

            // If target is greater than previous
            // to mid, return closest of two
            if (mid > 0 && target > arr[mid - 1])
                {
                  return getClosest(arr[mid - 1],arr[mid], target, mid-1,mid);
                }
            /* Repeat for left half */
            j = mid;
        }

        // If target is greater than mid
        else {
            if (mid < n - 1 && target < arr[mid + 1])
                return getClosest(arr[mid],  arr[mid + 1], target, mid,mid+1);
            // update i
            i = mid + 1;
        }
    }

    // Only single element left after search
    return mid;
}
```